# When adding a KeyListener object for some swing component outside of this component constructor KeyAdapter doesn't work

Tags: java, keylistener

When I try to add a KeyListener object for some swing component outside of this component constructor KeyListener doesn't answer after, why? For example:

```
    public class ActionViewer extends SimpleViewer
                              implements ActionListener

    {
        public ActionViewer(Dimension __wndSize, String pgnPath, 
                            PerspectiveProjection __persp)
        {
            super(__wndSize, pgnPath, __persp);

            ...
            cMng=null;
            ...
        }
        ///
        public void setCamera(double xMin, double xMax,
                              double yMin, double yMax,
                              double zMin, double zMax)
        {
            if(!isCameraInit())
            {
                if(cMng==null)
                    cMng=new CameraControl();
                this.addKeyListener((KeyListener)cMng);
                fCamInit=true;
            }
            setCameraBounds(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax);
        }
    ...
}
```

When I call setCamera in main there is nothing happen.

```
...
ActionViewer scene = new ActionViewer(wndSize, pgnPath, persp);
scene.setCamera(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax);
...
```

Comment: Your question is very vague and at least for me difficult to answer. Could you supply more context? Could you distill your code into a small compilable unit that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?  Do you know if the component with the key listener **has focus** (because focus is an absolute requirement for a KeyListener to work)? Often you're better off using key bindings rather than a KeyListener. Have you explored this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some problem of initialization, Could you check place of init listener just `try{}catch` all method `setCamera` and print all problems, it should help you to find problem.